# How to get all playlist available on apple music to my project

Tags: ios, swift

How to get all playlist available on apple music to my project . I want to access all apple music playlist ,Currently I am using MPMediaLibrary get playlist method but not getting any data or error?

```
`func getUserPlaylist()
    {
MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
print(status)
        }
        let lib = MPMediaLibrary()
       // let name = "playlist name"
       // let id:NSUUID = NSUUID()
       // let metadata = MPMediaPlaylistCreationMetadata.init(name: name)
       // metadata.authorDisplayName = "author"
       // metadata.descriptionText = "description"
        lib.getPlaylist(with:id as UUID, creationMetadata: nil) { (playlist, error) in
            guard error == nil
                else
            {
                print(error.debugDescription)
                return
            }
            if let currentPlaylist = playlist
            {
                print(currentPlaylist.name)
            }
        }
    } `
```

Answer (score 1):

To access Apple's music library, you will need to add the "Privacy - Media Library Usage Description" to your info.plist. Then you need to make your class conform to MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate. To display the Apple Music library, you present the MPMediaPickerController. To add the songs to an array, you implement the didPickMediaItems method of MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate.

```
    class MusicPicker:UIViewController, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {
//the songs the user will select
var selectedSongs: [URL]!

//this method is to display the music library. You might call it when a user taps a button to add songs to their playlist
func getSongs() {

var mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController?

mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .music)

mediaPicker?.delegate = self

mediaPicker?.allowsPickingMultipleItems = true

mediaPicker?.showsCloudItems = false
//present the music library
present(mediaPicker!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    //this is called when the user selects songs from the library
    func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
      //these are the songs that were selected. We are looping over the choices
      for mpMediaItem in mediaItemCollection.items {
 //the song url, add it to an array
let songUrl = mpMediaItem.assetURL
selectedSongs.append(songURL)
       }
       //dismiss the Apple Music Library after the user has selected their songs
       dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

       }
       //if the user clicks done or cancel, dismiss the Apple Music library
       func mediaPickerDidCancel(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController) {

      dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
       }
```

Comment: can't I do in my custom way ?, just for example I want to fetch all playlist as MPPlaylist objects and store all these in an array.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible. According to this page https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmediaplaylist Apple says MPMediaPlaylists are read-only to iOS devices. I am able to make a query for playlists using this code, which works, but I have not seen how to store the playlists. let myQuery = MPMediaQuery.playlists()
        
        let allPlaylists = myQuery.collections
        
        for thisPlaylist in allPlaylists! {
            
            print(thisPlaylist.value(forKey: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName))
            
        }

Answer (score 1):

I got all the playlist using the below code, I used MPMediaQuery class.

```
let query: MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.playlists()
        let playlists = query.collections
        guard playlists != nil else{
            return
        }
        for collection in playlists!{
            print(playlists?.description)
        }
```

Comment: Looks like Apple has deprecated MediaLibrary.  It says to use the iTunesLibrary framework instead.